# Is it possible to edebug a lambda returned by a function?

Tags: edebug, debug

For example,

```
(defun create-function (number)
  `(lambda () (* ,number ,number)))

(defalias 'square-two (create-function 2) "adds two")

(square-two)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Edebug does not support instrumenting code constructed at runtime.  If you try to instrument `create-function`, then the stepping will occur when you evaluate `(create-function 2)`, not when you execute `square-two`.

Edebug does support instrumenting `lambda` forms though, so you can rewrite your example using lexical binding:

```el
;;; -*- lexical-binding: t -*-
(defun get-lexical-function (number)
  (lambda () (* number number)))

(defalias 'square-two (get-lexical-function 2) "adds two")
```

Then if you instrument `get-lexical-function` **before** evaluating the `defalias` form, you can step through the `lambda` when evaluating `square-two`.

Comment: "Edebug does not support instrumenting code constructed at runtime." What does that mean? Are you not instrumented code constructed at runtime in your second example?

Comment: No, the code of the closure is already constructed, filling in the lexical binding doesn't make any new code.

Comment: I don't understand. I think we are thinking of two different "runtimes"

Answer (score 2):

Yes.

```
M-x debug-on-entry RET square-two RET

M-: (square-two) RET

Debugger entered--entering a function:
* square-two()
  eval((square-two) nil)
  eval-expression((square-two) nil nil 127)
  funcall-interactively(eval-expression (square-two) nil nil 127)
  call-interactively(eval-expression nil nil)
  command-execute(eval-expression)
```

Use `d` to step through the function.  Use `c` to skip through a step (skip substeps).  And as always, `C-h m` tells you more about the debugger, including other keys.

Comment: The question title mentioned `edebug`, not `debug`.

Comment: @npostavs: Hopefully someone will post an answer specific to edebug. I don't use edebug, so I can't help there. If edebug cannot be used for such a use case (I tried briefly, but I didn't find a useful solution), an alternative is to use the standard `debug`. But I imagine that edebug can be used for this too.

Comment: Yes, I'm primarily interested in `edebug`. I've tried using `edebug-on-entry` to little success.

Answer (score 1):

BTW, while npostavs's solution is the better option for your example, in those cases where you really do need to build the code manually with backquotes (e.g. inside `defmacro`), you can try:

```
(defun create-function (number)
  (edebug-\` (lambda () (* ,number ,number))))
```

Comment: Hmm, it's interesting, but I can't quite make it work. I get `(invalid-function square-two)`. Changing to `(defmacro create-function (number) (edebug-\` (* ,number ,number)))` produces working code, but I still can't manage to step through it.

Comment: Hmm... I guess it's broken somehow, then.  I know I've seen it working (back when I bumped into it some years ago while trying to fix something in Edebug), but I've never really made use of it.